# Brocade ISL port monitoring

Tags: storage-area-network, fibre-channel, fabric, brocade, isl

I have a pair of Brocade switches with ISLs running between them. I'd like to know if it's possible to be alerted when one of the ISL ports goes from an E_PORT to anything else (particularly a U_PORT). I am about to write a /sh script on a management box that will run a portshow command every 15 minutes and email me if it doesn't see what I need it to, but there has to be an easier way. How do you monitor your ISL ports?

Comment: Do you still need to nail down anything else related to this question?

Comment: Ideally, a link to something that would help future readers understand how MIBs work. In the end, we ended up incorporating this switch into our SNMP monitoring system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use snmpwalk and monitor `connUnitPortType` (1.3.6.1.3.94.1.10.1.3) from [FCMGMT-MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/FCMGMT-MIB.html).  Look for the index number of the port.  To index into the `connUnitPortType` table, you'll need to monitor with the index from `connUnitPortPhysicalNumber` (1.3.6.1.3.94.1.10.1.18)